# Start/stop an upstart process through Django admin command

Tags: python, django, upstart

I'm researching the optimum method of creating a python script which would run as a daemon and which I can start/stop through a custom Django admin command.

I've come to the conclusion that upstart might be the way to go, but I've not been able to find any examples of starting/stopping an upstart process in this way.

Does the above approach make sense - and if so could you provide an example of what command I would need to issue from Django?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adjust the following upstart script with your commands

```
#starting job on event
start on runlevel [345]
stop on runlevel [0126]

# Setup program environment
env PROG=/opt/django-projects/manage.py
env CONFIGCOMMAND=custom_admin

#Set the respawn flag for the service. It will be restarted
#if ended unexpectedly
respawn
respawn limit 3 5

# start program  
exec $PROG $CONFIGCOMMAND
```